# Class library compiled .DLL .NET

Tags: class, dll

Im trying to compile a simple class library project,its from Source Safe.
However,when i "build" project,then right click on project's BIN --> DLL --> Choose Properties,the Date modified doenst change,and i dont know if the DLL was recompiled with the new version.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1) **Build** won't recompile the dll if you haven't changed the source. If you want to forcibly recompile, use **Rebuild** or choose **Clean Solution** before building (cleaning deletes the old assembly).

2) Check to see whether you're looking at the correct build directory. By default, .NET comes with two configurations: Debug and Release. Each configuration has its own directory: e.g., `\Bin\Debug\*.dll`. Visual Studio only updates assemblies in the current configuration directory.

3) If you still can't tell whether your dll has changed, you can download [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) and inspect the file.

Comment: i did apply changes to code.So DLL must recompile,correct?
But,inside Debug directory or outside?